# Why I cannot catch some exception types in .NET?

Tags: .net, dllimport

We are working with some legacy DLLs on our C#/.NET project. Why some exception on the legacy code cannot be caught and the application crashes? What makes the difference with standard .NET exceptions?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the types of exceptions that are occurring, and possibly paste some code examples of how you've tried to catch them so far? Be glad to help if we can, and that kind of info would help us help you better. I'm guessing you may be seeing COMExceptions, but those should be catchable, so more info would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeffrey Ritcher, in his magnificent "CLR via C#", tells us: some unmanaged-code failures are considered "corrupted state exceptions" (CSEs) by the .Net Runtime (CLR). Usually (see later), these exceptions cannot be caught by us mere mortals. Even `finally` blocks aren't executed upon one of these failures, which include:

- Access violations
- Illegal instructions
- Stack overflows
- Page errors

You can, however, apply the [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute.aspx) and the [SecurityCriticalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securitycriticalattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) attributes to the specific method in which you expect CSEs to happen. Inside this method you can code a `try...catch` block which will catch the CSE.

Much more detailed information can be found in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx

Comment: I've been curious about this one for a very long time, and I've even got that book on my shelf. That'll teach me for not getting round to reading all of it!

Comment: It's about halfway through the book, under the "Unhandled Exceptions" section... sadly I only have the Kindle version, so I don't know which page it is.